# Make a list of the first 100 primes, keeping only ones whose last digit is less than 3

Tags: filtering, conditional, prime-numbers

This is a question from an "Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language" Section 28: Tests and Conditionals. We are asked to "Make a list of the first 100 primes, keeping only ones whose last 
digit is less than 3."

I think it should look something like this:

Select[Prime[Range[100]], f[#]<3 &]

where f[#] specifies a function that would select the last digit of each number.

However, I do not know how to create a condition on the last digit of a number?

Would somebody be able to help with this? Or point out where I've gone wrong so far. Thanks!

Comment: Select[Prime[Range[100]], Mod[#, 10] < 3 &]

Comment: `IntegerDigits` will give you a list of the digits that represent an integer. The `Last` function will give you the last element of a list. And `LessThan` will do a comparison for you. Try to put those together into a function. Come back with more questions if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: heh, or `Mod`--that's simpler. But now you don't get to try it on your own.

Comment: sorry to ruin the fun :( should've just suggested `Mod` instead of explicitly typing it all out

Comment: If you want a list of 100 such primes: ``primes = GeneralUtilities`NewIterator[MyPrimeIterator,
  {n = 0, p = 0},
  While[Mod[p = Prime[++n], 10] >= 3, Null]; p
  ]; GeneralUtilities`TakeIterator[primes, 100] // ReadList``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, since the cat's out of the bag, I guess we can proceed with our race-toward-ten. I'll provide a point-free solution to the original problem and avoid the OP's question about the specific `f`:

```
Select[Prime[Range[100]], LessThan[3]@*Last@*IntegerDigits]
```

Comment: Without `Composition` your answer gets a bit more readable: `Select[Prime[Range[100]], Last[IntegerDigits[#]] < 3 &]`

Comment: sure, but I said explicitly that I was providing a point-free solution.

Comment: Also, I always bristle when people assert that something's more readable as if there's an objective standard. I personally find the `Composition` expression more readable then the `Function` one.

Comment: I am aware that my comment concerning the readability is subjective.

Answer (score 9):

```
SolveValues[x <= Prime[100] && Mod[x, 10] < 3, x, Primes]
```

> ```
>  {2, 11, 31, 41, 61, 71, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 211, 241, 251,   
>   271, 281, 311, 331, 401, 421, 431, 461, 491, 521, 541}
> ```

Comment: love this one!!

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on my comment (first method)

1.

```
Select[Prime[Range[100]], Mod[#, 10] < 3 &]
```

here are two more (kind of cheating because 2 is an exception)

2.

```
Join[{2}, Select[Prime[Range[100]], Mod[#, 10] ==1 &]]
```

3. 

```
Join[{2},1+Select[Prime[Range[100]]-1,Divisible[#,10]&]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option using what the question asks, which is to use `f[#]`

```
p = Prime[Range[100]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[n_Integer?Positive] := Last[IntegerDigits[n]]
Select[p, f[#] < 3 &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

9 more different ways to do this are possible in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

Just to illustrate [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)

```
Flatten[Reap[
   Sow[#, Mod[#, 10]] & /@ Prime[Range[100]], _?(#1 <= 3 &)][[2]]]
```

yields:

{2, 3, 13, 23, 43, 53, 73, 83, 103, 113, 163, 173, 193, 223, 233, 
263, 283, 293, 313, 353, 373, 383, 433, 443, 463, 503, 523, 11, 31, 
41, 61, 71, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 211, 241, 251, 271, 281, 311, 
331, 401, 421, 431, 461, 491, 521, 541}

Answer (score 2):

As all valid primes other than `2` must end in `1`:

```
{2}~Join~(Prime[Range[100]]//Pick[#,Mod[#,10],1]&)

(* {2, 11, 31, 41, 61, 71, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 211,
 241, 251, 271, 281, 311, 331, 401, 421, 431, 461, 491, 521, 541} *)
```

Alternatively:

```
{2}~Join~(Prime[Range[100]]//Pick[#,NumberDigit[#,0],1]&)
```

**Original Answer**

```
Prime[Range[100]]//Pick[#,Clip[Mod[#,10]-3],-1]&
```